# Understanding completeness in this simple one-period exercise

Tags: risk-neutral-measure, arbitrage, pricing, asset-pricing, no-arbitrage-theory

Let's consider a one period model (t=0, 1) with one risk-free asset that yields r, and one risky asset. $S_t^j$ will be the value of the asset j=0,1 at time t=0,1, where j=0 is the risk-free asset and j=1 the risky asset. I will use a probability space with three states at t=1, being $\Omega = \{w^{-}, w, w^{+}\}$, all of them with strictly positive probability.

Now, let's consider exercise 1.6 of Nicolas Privault's Notes on Stochastic finance, chapter 1:

[image]

In this exercise, $w^{-}$ would correspond to a return of -b, $w$ a return of 0, and $w^{+}$ a return of +b. Solving a), we get that all possible risk-neutral probability measures are defined by $p^* = q^* = \frac{1-\theta^*}{2}$. Specifically, this means that there is at least one risk-neutral measure, so by The First Fundamental Theorem of Asset Pricing this market is without arbitrage. Also, by the second fundamental theorem, it is not a complete market since there are multiple risk-neutral measures.

Also, in part b), it puts a condition on the variance such that it can be shown that there is a unique risk-neutral measure. By the second fundamental theorem, this implies that the market is complete.

However, let's study this fact by elementary calculations:

Let's consider a contingent claim C, and let $C(w^{-})$, $C(w)$ and $C(w^{+})$ the payoff of the contingent claim in those states. Let's call $a^{-}:=S_1^1(w^{-})$, $a:=S_1^1(w)$ , $a^{+}=S_1^1(w^{+})$ the values of the risky asset at each final state in t=1. To build a portfolio ($\xi_0$, $\xi_1$) that replicates this contingent claim, we have to solve the system of equations:

$$
(1+r)\xi_0 + \xi_1a^{-} = C(w^{-})
$$
$$
(1+r)\xi_0 + \xi_1a = C(w)
$$
$$
(1+r)\xi_0 + \xi_1a^{+} = C(w^{+})
$$

For the market to be complete, this system has to have solutions for all contingent claims C. Now, this system of equations *does not* depend on any probability of the states, nor on the variance of the risky asset's returns. How is it possible that, if we impose the variance of the risky asset's returns, now the system has solutions for all contingent claims? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need the contingent claim calculation but the problem can be solved a little bit easier. (For the future, don't use b twice when meaning different things :)).

I think you can solve it like this:

So as you know by a) $\mathbb{E}^*(R_1)=0$. This means that $Var^*(R_1)=\mathbb{E}^*(R_1^2)$ (Assuming the star means with regards to the risk-neutral $P^*$ similar to the notation of expected value). So:

$$Var^*(R_1)=(-b)^2q^* + 0^2 \theta^* + b^2p^* = 2b^2 {p^*}^2 (= 2b^2 {q^*}^2)$$.

For a given $\sigma$ and $b$ you can solve $p^*$ (or $q^*$)(which given a) yields all other probabilities).

$$p^* = \frac{\sigma^2}{2b^2}$$

Because $\sigma^2 > 0, b>0$ this has a unique solution and defines one probability measure.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. But this really does not answer my question, as I am not asking about how to solve the problem. I am asking about how the way of computing it with contingent claims gives a result that does not depend on the variance of the assets returns

Comment: @ConfusedQuant Okay, sorry for that misunderstanding. I had another look at your proposed system of equations. Aren't you missing another equation that relates the  final payoff of $C$ to the current price of the contingent claim or am I now the confused quant?

Comment: I think I am not missing it, because I only want to find the portfolio that hedges the contingent claim. The current price of the contingent claim has to already match the current price of the hedging portfolio, because there is no arbitrage (a risk-neutral measure exists in this context).

Comment: I thought about the question again. I don't think you are able to replicate every (non-linear) payoff, in a three-state model with only two assets right?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. It is exemplifyied by the 3 equations that I included: 3 equations with two variables does not generally have a solution. However, if the variance is fixed (as in part b of the exercise), it should have always a replicating portfolio, by the uniqueness of the risk-neutral measure. Which is very strange, since the equations do not depend on the variance of the risky asset.

Comment: But you can not solve the three equations simultaneously (even for a fixed $p^*$). I believe that for the definition of complete markets (or for the applicability of the second fundamental theorem of asset pricing) you need at least as many stocks as states. (Maybe that is in the book which the exercise is from).

Comment: That makes sense. Although they don't mention it in the theorem. Let me reflect on this

Comment: Professor Ashwin Rao, from Stanford university proves it with n states and m+1 assets: https://web.stanford.edu/~ashlearn/RLForFinanceBook/ArbitrageCompleteness.pdf

Comment: Thank you. I read through it and the proof is very elegant. I think I found the problem. The 2nd FTAP states that: "Market is complete iff a unique risk-neutral probability measure exists".
As you have noted, the risk-neutral probability measure is not unique $\rightarrow$ the market is not complete. However you can prove that every risk-neutral probability measure (for example as constructed by Prof. Rao) has a different variance for the return. So you can select one prob measure, but this does not change anything about the market. (In essence the variance just tells you which one to choose)

Comment: The proof is very elegant indeed! (both 1st and 2nd theorems). Lets see if I've understood your answer: you mean that basically, fixing the variance of the risky asset does not change the market model? And therefore, it still has multiple risk-neutral measures (even if we have put a condition that only selects one)?

Comment: Thank you @MrLCh, I finally understood what you said. Today I am less Confused thanks to you!